# What is the minimum diameter of the spot a monochromatic beam can be focused to in relation to the beam wavelength?

Tags: optics, photonics

Can the beam be focused down to a spot with diameter less than two times the wavelength or even less than a single wavelength?

Comment: Search for diffraction limited systems and Abbe limit. Google goes a long way nowadays.

Comment: I see now, it wasn't immediately intuitive to me to relate focusing with diffraction.